# How to show data from endpoint in view with ploty?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using plotly to show heatmap. And I can show the heatmap with hardcoded data.

But now I have endpoint, so that you can see the heatmap with data from backend.

But if I am using the endpoint data I dont see the heatmap.

So this I have as template:

```
<plotly-plot [data]="graph.data" [layout]="graph.layout"

</plotly-plot>
```

and this typescript:

```
Map:map = {};

}
```

so this works and I see the heatmap.

But now if I do this:

```
export interface map { 
  

    map?: Array<Array<number>> | null;
}
```

```
 Map() {

    this.Service
        
        });
  }




But then the data is not visible

So what I have to change?

So I have it now like this:
```

this.showHeadMap().subscribe((res) => {

}

Because it is using a source as image.

But if I load the page I see just a graph for one second and if the page loading is finished. then the graph disappear. But the image is not shown.

```
But if I fill in the z with this:
```

z: [[0.000010752661,

```
you have to do this:
```

z: [[res.push(this.ok.map[0])]],

```
but then for all values
```

Comment: you are getting any error?

Comment: No, that is the strange thing. I dont get any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change showHeadMap To following :-

```
showHeadMap() {

    return this.aggregateCameraHeatmapsService
        .aggregateHeatmaps('2020-11-09 10:00:00', '2020-12-10 14:15:00', 4, '1')
        .pipe(map((res) => {
             this.cameraAgretateHeadMap.heatmap = res.heatmap.slice(0, 1);
             return this.cameraAgretateHeadMap.heatmap;
         }));
  }
```

then assign graph like :-

```
this.showHeadMap().subscribe((res) => {
 this.graph = {
  data: [
    {
       z: [res],
       type: 'heatmap',
       showscale: false,
       colorscale: colorScale,
       opacity: 0.7,
       zsmooth: 'best'
    }
  ]
 }
});
```

Comment: Thats another question, don't you think?